# AWS Iot no activity logged

Tags: iot, aws-iot

I am trying to find the connected devices and according to the forums and was advised to subscribe to "$aws/events/presence/+".

I have created two clients where one subscribes to the "$aws/events/presence/+" topic and the other one sends the connect command.

I could not see any activity under the tab.

Could you please help me to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

There is a subtopic to the `presence` topic that you need to consider by either adding the subtopic or using the multi-level topic wildcard (`#` instead of `+`). This means you need to subscribe to `$aws/events/presence/connected/+` (or `$aws/events/presence/#` to monitor both connections and disconnections).

This accounts for the `connected` and `disconnected` subtopics on the [reserved topics](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/reserved-topics.html) `$aws/events/presence/connected/clientId` and `$aws/events/presence/disconnected/clientId`.